# Ubuntu 23.04 clamtk: libjson-c.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: malware, clamav, signature, clamtk

I cant use the program for years now. What is wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The `libjson-c.so.3` file is quite old. Has your Ubuntu installation been regularly upgraded from 20.04? If you would like to use Clam, it may be necessary to first remove it, then re-install the packages. This should acquire the newer libraries.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried to update and now to remove the version by apt. Clamtk struggles furthermore with the old libsjon-c.so.3. How can i remove it?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove Clam or how to remove the `libjson` library?

Comment: I suppose it should be removed  libsjon-c.so.3. 
After i have removed and new installed clamtk  and start the program,
I get the message in terminal: 
"usr/bin/sigtool: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

So its not possible to run clamtk.

Comment: I wonder where that Clam is coming from. Looking [at the package for 23.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/clamtk), there is no dependency on `libjson-c`. A JSON Perl library is used, but that does not call the missing file ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've never got and seen that package. 
I remove that old one now with:  apt-get purge clamav clamtk.
I get maybe the same trouble if i install it afterwards with apt install clamav clamtk?
There is no difference to the old names.

Comment: Ok. After installing again I get the same failure:
usr/bin/sigtool: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Both programmes clamtk and clamd in the terminal show at fail with libjson-c.so.3.

Comment: Update:
There exsist Unity and Ubuntu as choice during logon.
Under Unity i can run clam but obviously not in a proper mode.
It stops after a scan from about 60 files in the home directory.
Whats wrong here?

Comment: Was Unity installed recently? Or was it originally installed with the version of Ubuntu that had it? Something tells me you’re using a system that has been used for many, many years, and receiving regular upgrades. This may be the result of some “cruft” that has accumulated between the bigger updates, as Ubuntu has seen a lot change under the covers since Unity was replaced with Gnome 

Comment: "Was Unity installed recently? Or was it originally installed with the version of Ubuntu that had it?..."
-It is an old part of Ubuntu.  I thought Gnome too undependently from the names which
one can see.

Comment: Anyone who can help?
There is a conflict with libjson-c.so.3